# Explain why there's a different result when converting a binary number to decimal, and when converting its two's complement to decimal

Tags: binary, decimal, signed, twos-complement, decimal-point

For example, we're given the number -1.5(10).

Converting it to signed binary we get 11.1000(2).

Its two's complement is 00.1000(2), which is 0.5(10) when converted to decimal.

Which is self-explanatory, because it's a different binary number.

What else is there to explain?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing apples (signed-binary) and oranges (two's complement).

You took a negative value in one representation (signed-binary), negated it using the technique for a *different* representation (2's complement), and (unsurprisingly) ended up with trash as a result.

If you had negated 11.1000(2) as appropriate for signed-binary, you'd end up with 01.1000(2) -- the correct answer.

If you had *started* with the 2's complement representation of -1.5, 10.1000(2), and took the 2's complement of *that*, you'd end up with 01.1000(2) -- also correct.

Note that *none* of this involves converting anything to decimal.